# First item in listbox always gets read instead of selected (highlighted) item in listbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, listbox, viewstate

Let me try that again here... my Delete function in ASP.NET webform here:

```
        //delete a product from the product list 
    protected void btn_Del_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int index = lst_Products.SelectedIndex;  //<=== this is the code that gets me stumped. 
                                                 //index keeps returning 0 (zero) whether postback or not

        //Store product cID and FullLine for LINQ compare
        string pFullLine = lst_Products.Items[index].ToString();
        int cID = Convert.ToInt32(lst_Products.Items[index].Value);

        // Read ViewState
        List<Product> allProducts = (List<Product>)ViewState["products"];

        List<Product> productsfiltered = allProducts
                                         .Where(product => product.CategoryId == cID && product.FullLine == pFullLine).ToList();

        foreach (Product prodToDelete in productsfiltered)
        {
            //delete it.  Most of the time this would only be one item, but more than one entry is possible.
            allProducts.Remove(prodToDelete);
        }

        //store modified product list
        ViewState["products"] = allProducts;


        //lst_Products.DataBind();
        //BindProdData();

        //display products
        ShowProd();

        //show cat ID in Product ID textbox (product ID always = Category ID)
        txt_ProdID.Text = cID.ToString();

    }
```

The arrow in the code shows where the problem occurs: `lst_Products.SelectedIndex` is giving the wrong index value pointing to first item shown in the listbox, `lst_Products`, which points to index 0 instead of index 1 (the highlighted entry in the listbox).  Take a look at this image below:

[image: Code snippets with debugging data and "Existing Products:" lst_Products listbox]

Am I misunderstanding the purpose of the `SelectedIndex` part of the code?  I thought it's suppose to read the highlighted item.  If not, what can I do to read the selected (highlighted) item in the listbox?

Below is a smaller part of my code with debugging data for comparison:

[image: Smaller code snippet with debugging data embedded]

Specifically, I mouse-select index 1 in the listbox to highlight it, then hit the delete button, but index 0 gets deleted instead.

So my questions are:

1. Why is index 0 "selected=true" despite my highlighting index 1 in the listbox?
2. How do I get index 1 (or other than index 0) selected so that it gets snagged by my delete routine to delete it? I'm trying to derive the text string from the listbox based on the index.
3. Is there a more appropriate code for doing the same thing?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: How do you add the item in listbox? Is it datasource? or manually adding the items like listbox.items.add("some data");

Comment: do you get correct value in lst_Products.SelectedValue ?

Comment: @CST It comes from ViewState. This part of the code is also working.

Comment: Can you share the aspx code of listbox

Comment: @Mainak Yes, it's getting the correct value.  (Sorry, I misread your question.)

Comment: @Akshay listbox code: '<asp:ListBox ID="lst_Products" runat="server" Height="138px" Width="250px"></asp:ListBox>'

Comment: How are the list items added to it?

Comment: The listbox contains only some of the data from ViewState that filters out those that have the same "cId," or the product ID, which is "5" in this case. The two items both have the same ID, "5," but different product name strings.  They are not manually added to the listbox, they ultimately come from hardcoded statements saved to ViewState.

Comment: like you have done SelectedValue try SelectedText in place of SelectedItem.Text

Comment: No such thing as SelectedText.

Comment: (Stupid blocking of my answer.)  Based on tests on a different solution code with a similar function, I've come to the conclusion that `SelectedItem.Text` or `SelectedValue` does **not** mean highlighted entry as shown on the listbox.  It simply means the first-encountered entry in the list with the selected value, regardless of whether it's highlighted or not.  Therefore, the data structure must include a unique ID for every entry created.  This guarantees the right entry will be deleted.

Comment: Problem solved by adding unique ID and using SelectedValue to obtain it, as I mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried following ?

```
DropDownList1.Items[DropDownList1.SelectedIndex].Value
```

Comment: Anyway, it's a listbox, not a dropdownlist.

Comment: oh i am sorry i didn't see that

Comment: i'll check for another solution may be if i could help

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with a listbox on a Winform - the first item in the list was selected automatically.  I cleared the selection list first (VB.NET code):

```
lboxMembershipTypes.SelectedItems.Clear()
```

Then I selected the items in the listbox based on the items selected in my dataset:

```
'check each row in the dataset

For Each MembershipROW In MyDataset.Tables(0).Rows

'select this membership type in the listbox

MembershipType = MembershipROW.Item("MembershipType")

MembershipIndex = lboxMembershipTypes.FindStringExact(MembershipType)

'is this membership in our list?

If (MembershipIndex <> ListBox.NoMatches) Then

  'is this membership selected?

   If (MembershipROW.Item("SelectMembership")) Then

     'select this membership type

     lboxMembershipTypes.SetSelected(MembershipIndex, True)

   End If

 End If

Next
```

I did a more general solution than simply checking if the first item was selected and if not then unselect it - however, that would work too.

Comment: Sorry but I couldn't get all the code to be highlighted so please note the "For Each..." is the start of the section of code and the "Next" at the bottom is the end of the code.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread. but 2.5 years later i'm having the same issue with little luck on google and found this thread with the exact same issue (even down to the debug example).

I resolved the issue by removing duplicate listitem values by making them unique. I had this listbox databound to a linq var coming from a namevaluecollection with duplicates (yes i didn't want a dictionary since i wanted to group members by department and wanted department as a key).

This is what i was doing for the datasource and was getting the issue:
`var members = nvc_members.AllKeys.SelectMany(nvc_members.GetValues, (k, v) => new { key = k, value = v })` 
and then i would assign the key to the value and the value to the text in the datalist.
This change worked for me to make unique values in the listbox:
`var members = nvc_members.AllKeys.SelectMany(nvc_members.GetValues, (k, v) => new { key = k+"-"+v, value = v })`

This could have probably been avoided if i'd just gone with a dictionary in the beginning and made unique keys the same way, but then i wouldn't have ended up here.